# How to change value of appended select element in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this form where there is one select element originally but the user can add the number of select when clicking on 'add'. Then when the user submitted the form, and there are some invalid input (i.e unfilled input) the form is not submitted ( I am using php for form validation), and it goes back to the original page with only 1 select displayed, so I use jquery and count the array of the select submitted and append the select elements as much as the user chosen at first. Now the problem is how do I set the value of the appended select to be the value that the user has chosen ?

Sorry for the bad explanation, here is the code, hope it helps giving a clearer picture :

html

```
<div class='select_container'>
    <select name='select[]'>
       <option value='option1'>Option1</option>
        <option value='option2'>Option2</option>
        <option value='option3'>Option3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class='add'>Add</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //User can add more select element by clicking 'add'

    $('.add').click(function() {
        $('<select name="select[]">' +
          '<option value="option1">Option1</option>' +
          '<option value="option2">Option2</option>' +
          '<option value="option3">Option3</option>' +
          '</select>').appendTo('.select_container');
    });

    //When form failed to submit(i.e invalid input), automatically 
    //add the select element as many as the user added at first

    //get the user select input, make it into array

    var select = "<?php $select= echo implode(',',$_POST['select']); ?>";
    var select_array = select.split(',');
    var select_length = select_array.length;

    //after counting length of array, add the amount of select element the user added

    for (i = 1; i < select_length; i++) {
        $('<select name="select[]">' +
          '<option value="option1">Option1</option>' +
          '<option value="option2">Option2</option>' +
          '<option value="option3">Option3</option>' +
          '</select>').appendTo('.select_container');
    }
});
```

I managed to append the select element so that when form failed to submit, user did not have to re-add the select element, and I want the appended select element when the form failed to submit to automatically set to the value that the user chosen.

I have tried `delegate()`, `on()` and a bunch of other stuff, but I am still unable to set the value of the appended select elements. I was only able to set the value of the original first select in the `html`.

Please if anyone knows a way to set the value of the appended select, all answers and suggestions are greatly welcomed and appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If the submit does fail on php side you can store those data on session (example) and the use them on page reload.

Comment: But I want the select element to show and display the chosen item by the user. (scenario example : A user added 3 select element, and he chose : option1, option2, option3, option1). This will turn out error because there is a duplicated option chosen, and it goes back to the form page, when it goes back, I want the form to have already 4 select elements with the users choices, so that maybe he want to change the last option to option4 or something, and that the user does not have to re-add the select and re-choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that options stay same, You may do it simply by submitting the form to the same page(current page) and In your php file, html part should look like this

```
 <div class='select_container'>
    <select name='select[]'>
       <option value='option1'>Option1</option>
        <option value='option2'>Option2</option>
        <option value='option3'>Option3</option>
    </select>
 <?php
      if(!isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST['select'])){
         for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_POST['select']);$i++){
           echo '<select>';
             $options=array('option1','option2','option3');
             for($j=0;$j<sizeof($options)){
                 if($options[$j]==$_POST['select'][$i]){
                    echo '<option 
                          value="'.$options[$j].'" 
                          selected="selected">'.$options[$j].'</option>';
                 }else{
                    echo  '<option
                     value="'.$options[$j].'">'.$options[$j].'</option>';
                 }
             }
           echo '</select>';
         }
      }
 ?>
</div>

<div class='add'>Add</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a very great answer,but I don't think I can apply this in my case, because actually in my form there are 2 selects (select of states & select of cities), for each option of the state, there is a select option of the cities inside that state, so I am actually appending two selects(states and cities) each time the user click the add button. I need so that when the form failed to submit, it is in the same page and the state and city select are automatically selected to the value that the user has chosen. I am trying to use your method though and see if it can work.

Comment: Actually I managed to get what I need by combining your answer and @Derenir answer. I echo the select elements and manipulate it using jquery. Thank you for the help. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (I'm assuming you post the form back to the same file):

```
//  if reloaded after post basically
if( select.length > 0 ) {
    //  if there are multiple groups of selects, add class and call each on that
    $('select').each(function(i) {
        $(this).val( select_array[i] );

    });

}
```

The order of the selects are guaranteed due to the linear nature of the form processing, so that should't be a problem.

Comment: Thx for your answer, this is almost close to what I need, It only changed the value of the first original select though, as for the other appended selects, it doesn't change, I'm guessing because the other selects are appended ?

Comment: @Charas, it shouldn't be a problem if its appended or not, at least in the small demo i put together it isn't. If you still need a solution, i can put a JSFiddle together.

Comment: I have finally be able to get what I need by using the method provided by Bellash on top, and thanks to you too I used your method to manipulate the select elements after being produced using php. Sorry I voted correct answer for Bellash, I upvoted you answer though, cause both of your answer combined is what I need. Many Thanks.